Laptop Speakers Are Not Detected on Ubuntu 24.04
I have installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my HP Chromebook 13 G1 laptop. I used Mrchromebox to get Ubuntu installed on my laptop. Everything works except for audio using the laptop speakers. If I connect my Bluetooth headphones to the laptop audio works fine.
When I have no headphones attached in the Sound settings for the Output device is states Dummy Output. When I have my Bluetooth headphones attached they show under the Output device.
When I run this command: sudo apt list --installed | grep linux-image I get the following:
linux-image-6.8.0-50-generic/noble-updates,noble-security,now 6.8.0-50.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04/noble-updates,noble-security,now 6.8.0-50.51 amd64 [installed,automatic]

When I run this command: lspci | grep audio I get the following:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

In some threads, I am seeing updates made to GRUB ir the intel driver.
When I run this command: inxi -A
I get the following output:
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-51-generic status: kernel-api
Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active
When I run the following command: sudo nano /etc/default/grub
The following is displayed:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
Should snd_hda_intel be appearing after GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT? My setup has "quiet splash" here.

Please post the output of lspci | grep audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

Does this Help?

Hi @eyoung100, I tried installing sof-firmware and rebooting and still have no sound from my laptop speakers.

After reading @mondotofu's answer, do you have multiple sound cards?  Press F6 in alsamixer

have you tried alsamixer ?
It allows you to see all your audio input and output devices and the current volume levels.
You can press the tab key to change the audio device. You might find your built in speakers are either "M" for muted or turned down to 0.
Use the up arrow key to raise the volume if that's the case.
If that doesn't help, you could execute a utility called alsa-info to gather extensive data about your audio configuration. When prompted, don't upload the data.  You will then be given the name of the file in your /tmp directory where the metadata has been gathered.  The level of detail is beyond me, but try alsamixer first.  Its retro interface is not so bad, and it has long been a tool in Ubuntu distributions.

Thanks for the reply. When I use the alsamixer, it shows that I have a card and a chip there. I have confirmed that the volume is up, but still no sound from the laptop speakers. Bluetooth headphones are working fine.
